# Language that describes all real numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_real_number):

> Suppose that in a mathematical language $L$, it is possible to enumerate all of the defined numbers in $L$. Let this enumeration be defined by the function $G\colon W\to \mathbb R$, where $G(n)$ is the real number described by the $n$th description in the sequence. Using the diagonal argument, it is possible to define a real number $x$, which is not equal to $G(n)$ for any $n$. This means that there is a language $L'$ that defines $x$, which is undefinable in $L$.

Does it mean there exists a language that can define all real numbers, produced by the diagonal argument?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does a bijection from the reals to the any binary form?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339827/does-a-bijection-from-the-reals-to-the-any-binary-form)

Comment: Definitely not if the language consists of countably many symbols.

Comment: @Peter: Well... if your logic is $\cal L_{\omega_1,\omega}$... :-)

Answer (score 3):

Well, it depends what you mean by "language." Any countable language will fail to describe every real number, by that argument. However, if we allow *uncountable* languages, then of course every real can be described by such a language - e.g., a language containing a symbol for each real number.

---

An important aspect of this answer is that I am talking about the "real" universe (whatever that means). There are models of set theory in which every element - not just every real! - is first-order definable in the language of set theory; such models are called "pointwise definable" and have been studied by Joel David Hamkins and others. Note that such models are necessarily countable.

Answer (score 3):

This is a delicate issue. What do you mean by "describe"?

Can you describe $\pi$ using just the field operations on $\Bbb R$? No. You cannot. But you can, if you allow using $\leq$ and $\sin$ (it is the least positive root of $\sin$).

You can describe $\pi$ if you extend your universe to allow sets of reals, and the only set of real you've added is $\{\pi\}$.

So what exactly does it mean "describe all the real numbers"? This can take two meanings.

1. We have a language $\cal L$ and the real numbers are a structure to this language somehow. Can every element of $\Bbb R$ be definable using an $\cal L$-formula?

   The answer to that is yes, assuming we allow a sufficiently large language. If $\cal L$ is simply continuum many constant symbols, and the structure of $\Bbb R$ interprets each real as a unique constant symbol, then you can easily describe each real number. If the language is countable, then the answer is of course negative.

   The answer is also positive if you're using a logic which allows infinitely many conjunctions, and in a language where you can define all the rational numbers. Then you can just describe each real number by saying which rational numbers are smaller and which are bigger.
2. We can allow a much much larger universe in which we want to describe the real numbers. So for example you can ask, in the set theoretic universe, is it possible that every real number can be defined by a unique formula? The answer to that is in fact positive. It is possible to have a universe of set theory where *every* set is definable. The catch is that the definitions are not objects of *that* universe, but rather they live in a lovely place called the meta-universe. But this requires better understanding in both set theory and logic, so I'll just leave this as an anecdote.

Comment: "describe" as in the context that is used in that quoted article.

Comment: Have you seen the bunch of notices about the quality and content dispute of that article? They're not there for no reason.

Comment: Well, I haven't. I am just a fan of mathematics, and this made me wondering. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm not saying that you should be able to referee the content of the Wikipedia page yourself. Just that you should notice that these sort of banners appear on the top. They are there for a good reason. Many mathematical topics can be broad-strokingly described easily, but once you start asking questions like yours, the broad strokes are not enough, and you need to start getting into the gritty details.

Comment: Another issue about "describe:" given any two distinct reals $r<s$, there is a first-order sentence distinguishing them (pick a rational $q$ between $r$ and $s$, and consider ". . . is real number $<q$"). Does this count as "describing" every real, to you?

Comment: @Noah: The fact that two things can be separated doesn't mean that they can be described.

Comment: @AsafKaragila my point was that one needs to specify what "describe" means. Of course when I use the word "describe" I don't mean it in this sense, but I think there is still an intuitive connection that one can get tripped up on here.

Comment: @Noah: I agree, which is why I also agree very much with the banners on top of that Wikipedia page (which is indeed in a sore need of a complete rewrite). But I think that it's not hard to guess that "describe" means "define" in this context.

Answer (score 1):

If you believe in set (and class) theory that admits semisets, i.e., if you believe that there are subcollections of sets that are not sets, then you don't have to believe that there are real numbers which can't be written down in a countable language. If you believe in semisets, a function sending each real number to the smallest corresponding Godel number could be considered a class rather than a set, even though it is an injective correspondence between sets (and so possessed of a graph which is a subcollection of a set), which would avoid contradicting the uncountability of the reals. The point is that the correspondence involves in its definition the universe of sets, and so need not be a set (and in fact must be a class).

If you don't believe separation or replacement axioms should be allowed to create sets from sets (by relativizing the axioms to the universe of sets) unless the statements involved in them do not refer to the universe of sets (or higher universes), then that means you believe in semisets. In fact, it seems to me that formally that's the only restriction you need to create a theory of semisets from a typical standard theory of sets with universes (which would believe all subcollections of sets are sets). I'm not sure how analogous my not-entirely-thought-out simple way of allowing semisets is to that of Petr Vopěnka and Petr Hájek in the 1972 *The Theory of Semisets*, which stylistically is oddly opaque and something I am reluctant to wrap myself around. Anyway, allowing semisets seems entirely preferable to me compared to the standard way of doing things, and is actually the conservative thing to do.

Comment: Traditionally, Godel numbers are natural numbers. While I don't know enough about semisets, I don't believe they allow an injection from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Cf. page 400 of [Why Semisets?](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/105499) by Petr Hájek. He mentions that one may add to the theory of semisets "the axiom (GC) of general (semiset-) countability saying that any two infinite sets are semiset equivalent." The footnote on the next page mentions how effective this be in obviating what he calls the "Löwenheim-Skolem paradox".